# Random number with sass

Tags: css, sass

So I'm using sass and I'm trying to get a random number. this is my code

```
$random-num: random(365);

.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: rgba ($random-num, 90, 50, 1);

}
```

When I look at the generated css it evaluates to

```
background-color: rbga(random(365), 90, 50, 1);
```

Why wont random evaluate? I have latest version of sass installed. (3.3.4)

Comment: I'm curious: what's the point of `random()` if the number is only generated once, when you compile the CSS? It's not like it changes every time the page is loaded. Why not just pick a color?

Comment: Oh. The css isn't generated everytime you reload the page?

Comment: Nope. SASS produces regular CSS, it's not magic. Also 365 is out of bounds anyways, you'd want 255.

Comment: Roger that... I thought it compiled every time the page loaded. I guess I will delete this question. Thanks.